# Not Exists Query with additional filters

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a query for not exists which doesn't give proper results. However, using the same query with minus it's gives the correct results. Can anyone please tell me where i am getting it wrong. Below are the two codes:

Not exists:

```
    SEL DISTINCT Accs_Meth_Id FROM X.DIM_LINE  A
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
SEL 1 
FROM X.DIM_PRODUCT B 
WHERE A.ACCS_METH_ID=B.ACCS_METH_ID
AND A.STATUS <> 'A'
AND B.STATUS <> 'A'
);
```

Minus:

```
SEL DISTINCT ACCS_METH_ID FROM X.DIM_LINE 
WHERE STATUS<>'A'
MINUS
SEL DISTINCT ACCS_METH_ID FROM X.DIM_PRODUCT 
WHERE STATUS<>'A'
```

Thanks,
AMiT

Answer (score 3):

Get the condition `A.STATUS <> 'A'` out of subquery

```
SEL DISTINCT Accs_Meth_Id FROM X.DIM_LINE  A
WHERE 
A.STATUS <> 'A'
AND
NOT EXISTS 
(
SEL 1 
FROM X.DIM_PRODUCT B 
WHERE A.ACCS_METH_ID=B.ACCS_METH_ID    
AND B.STATUS <> 'A'
);
```

Comment: Thanks Tedo..my bad.